# Get json object with specific condition from an array of json objects using restangular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, restangular

If I am getting data from a json api (playlists.json), and the playlist object has a `user_id` data field, how can I get a specific playlist with `user_id == 1`?

I tried doing:

```
var playlists = Restangular.all('playlists');

playlists.getList().then(function(data) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var obj = data[i];
        if(obj.user_id == 1) {
            $scope.playlist = obj;                
        }
    }
});
```

But I would rather not retrieve all the playlists and loop through all of them as it seems very inefficient.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whether you do it, or let a framework do it, there will be a loop happening. Unless you can make a separate json file.

Answer (score 2):

If `json api` represents collection of `playlist` you can use:

```
Restangular.one('user_id', 1).then(function(data) {   
    $scope.playlist = data;  
});
```

But if you want preloaded list, I think there is no way but use loop

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
playlists.getList().then(function(data) {
        angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
            if(value.user_id == 1) {
                scope.playlist = value;
                return;
            }
        });

    });
```